# $q.all with angular resource defer call twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing angular 1 app. I am using `$q.all` with deferred for angular resource as below. The reason is that I need to reject the promise in success response.

However, it seems that when i implemented as below, the query is being executed twice. Appreciate if someone could identify the problem and suggestion on how to resolve this.

```
$q.all([
    searchA(),
    searchB()
]).then(function(res) {

}, function (err) {

});

function searchA() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    Api.searchA().$promise.then(function (res) {
        if (res && res.results) {
            defer.resolve(res);
        } else {
            defer.reject(res);
        }
    }, function (err) {
        defer.reject(err);
    });
    return defer.promise;
}

function searchB() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    Api.searchB().$promise.then(function (res) {
        if (res && res.results) {
            defer.resolve(res);
        } else {
            defer.reject(res);
        }
    }, function (err) {
        defer.reject(err);
    });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: How are you triggering the `$q.all()`? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: "the query is being executed twice" which query?

Comment: @quirimmo searchA and searchB executed twice

Comment: Works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/AgMxXKlp2x1HIqgWdg4x?p=preview. Problem is in something you are not showing. Note you don't need `$promise` in `$q.all().then()`

Comment: As pointed out by @charlietfl, the double call is something related outside the code you provided. Try to take a look to the code where the shown code gets executed instead

Comment: Is this being called by a function in the view? If so would be called every digest in a cycle which is minimum of 2 and sometimes more

Comment: @charlietfl could you explain what do you mean by being called by a function in the view?

Comment: Like `{{ doSearch()}}` where `doSearch()` has the `$q.all()` call